MarkLogic Document Conversion
I am using xdmp:word-convert to convert DOC/DOCX files to XHTML and xdmp:pdf-convert for PDF to XHTML conversion. While the conversion works as expected for smaller files (e.g., a 28KB document), it fails to produce any output for larger files, such as a 119MB DOC file.
It doesn't return anything (just an empty sequence).
I need to convert large DOC/DOCX/PDF files to XHTML effectively in MarkLogic. Can anyone provide technical guidance on handling this issue?
import module namespace c = "http://marklogic.com/leapfrog/config" at "/ada/config.xqy";


let $source1 := xdmp:document-get("file:///C:/28-KB-file.doc")
let $source := xdmp:document-get("file:///C:/119-MB-doc-file.doc")


let $new-uri := "document.doc"
let $doc-format := $c:doc-format-doc
let $results :=
switch ($doc-format)
    case $c:doc-format-doc return                                   
        xdmp:word-convert($source, $new-uri)
    case $c:doc-format-ppt return
        xdmp:powerpoint-convert($source, $new-uri)
    case $c:doc-format-xls return
        xdmp:excel-convert($source, $new-uri)
    default return
        xdmp:pdf-convert($source, $new-uri)
return $results


So, it doesn't return anything (just an empty sequence)? Are there any clues in the logs (errors or warnings that there might be a problem parsing the file, memory limits, etc.)?

Thank you @MadsHansen for your assistance. Unfortunately, there are no relevant clues in the logs. I have also tried increasing the memory, cache, and threshold parameters, but this has not resolved the issue.

@MadsHansen In addition to increasing the parameters, I utilized xdmp:document-filter to convert the document to XHTML. This approach successfully converts the document, but embedded content such as images and tables referenced in the parent files are missing.

It would be easier to investigate/help if we had access to the files. You might consider opening a MarkLogic Support case and uploading those files to see if they can reproduce and determine if there might be an issue with the files themselves, a bug/issue, or are hitting some limit.
